# Making a loop with script using cv2 that converts video to images

Tags: python, loops, opencv

I am a beginner using python so this is probably relatively simple, but I would like to make a script I found online using Open CV into a loop so that it can convert a whole folder of videos into images.

This code works well when I put in a video file name to `cv2.VideoCapture()` but I have run into issues when trying to define it as a variable name that a loop can reference. So any help in how to structure the loop and subroutine correctly would be extremely helpful!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('FS_T8_2019-01-17_02.14.52_.MP4')

def getFrame(sec):
    vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,sec*1000)
    hasFrames,image = vidcap.read()
    if hasFrames:
        cv2.imwrite("image"+str(count)+".jpg", image)     # save frame as JPG file
    return hasFrames
sec = 0
frameRate = 1 #//it will capture image in each 1 second
count=1
success = getFrame(sec)
while success:
    count = count + 1
    sec = sec + frameRate
    sec = round(sec, 2)
    success = getFrame(sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ideally want to move the vidcap inside the getFrame function to get the video source as an argument so that vidcap will differ for every video. I looped over a folder(videos) and outputting the frames to another folder(output) like this

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
ROOT_DIRECTORY_PATH = sys.path[0]


def getFrame(sec, src, img_out):
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
    vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, sec * 1000)
    hasFrames, image = vidcap.read()
    if hasFrames:
        cv2.imwrite(img_out, image)     # save frame as JPG file
    return hasFrames

def create_frame(src, dst):
    sec = 0
    frameRate = 1  # //it will capture image in each 1 second
    count = 1
    img_out = dst + '_' + str(count) + '.jpg'
    success = getFrame(sec, src, img_out)
    while success:
        count = count + 1
        sec = sec + frameRate
        sec = round(sec, 2)
        img_out = dst + '_' + str(count) + '.jpg'
        success = getFrame(sec, src, img_out)

for mp4name in os.listdir('videos'):
    create_frame(ROOT_DIRECTORY_PATH + '/videos/' + mp4name,
                 ROOT_DIRECTORY_PATH + '/output/' + mp4name.split('.mp4')[0])
```

Comment: So this worked perfectly the first time I ran it, but when I tried with a different folder I got this error:
OpenCV: Couldn't read video stream from file "/Users/ccclab/Desktop/Users/ccclab/Desktop/empty vids/IMG_0196.MP4" The file type was exactly the same, so I'm not sure what is going on now.

Comment: "/Users/ccclab/Desktop" this shows up twice in your path, try printing out ROOT_DIRECTORY_PATH and see what it shows